# InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code - error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, web-services

Using C#, I am attempting to consume a web service that was created in Java and deployed on a WebLogic server. I am using VS 2008 and have created an ASP.NET Web Site. I added the service as a web reference and it appears that the classes are available. I attempt to consume the service with the following code:

```
    ShippingApplicationService ship = new ShippingApplicationService();
    CollectionPlanInfo cp = ship.getCollectionPlanInfo("TEST1","122");
```

The web site builds successfully. However, when I run the above code I receive the following error:

InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know without looking at the generated proxy.
But may be ship.getCollectionPlanInfo(..) is expecting an string[] (or variable arguments).
Try

```
CollectionPlanInfo cp = ship.getCollectionPlanInfo(string[] { "TEST1","122" });
```

Again... I'm totally guessing here... b/c I don't have the proxy.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The error is on the first line of code:
    ShippingApplicationService ship = new ShippingApplicationService();